# Encrypting db connection string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

I come from .NET world.

In python code I have database connection string. Is there any way to keep these connection strings encrypted within python code?

Comment: You have a possibility to keep it as a config file , with encrypted content. Why in code?

Comment: @Kris Even if it is a config file, where should the keys be kept for decrypting?

Comment: Another question against the question, how would the connection config get exposed? Logs? . I think keys could be another set of config lol!

Comment: If the code can decrypt it you can extract it with a simple code change.

Comment: @Kris Any open-source key vault like Azure Key Vault from where keys can be accessed using a token?

Comment: I think the best way to deal with this is use an environment variable/ startup-parameter to hold your decryption key and keep the configurations encrypted. So even if you want to ship the config to a different location, the decryption key can be safely exchanged. Do you differ?

Comment: @Kris Please post this as answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: Sure. I have Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securing the DB configuration or any sensitive configurations can be done by keeping configs encrypted. In python you can do it using packages like `secureconfig` or `encrypted-config` or DIY with some standard encryption techniques.

Keeping the encryption keys outside is the next challenge, which you can tackle by making it a injected config via `environmental variables` or a `command-line-parameter`.